# Receive SMS on the basis of specific contacts

Tags: android, sms, contacts

I am developing an SMS app for hiding SMS of some specific contacts selected from contacts list. After selection on clicking the button contacts are added to SQLite database as follows:

```
 btn_select.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int len = selection.length;
            int cnt = 0;
            String selectIds = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                if (selection[i]) {

                    cnt++;
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < selection_val.size(); i++) {

                selectedData[i]=selection_val.get(i);
                selectIds = selectIds + " | " + selection_val.get(i);
            }
            addContacts(selectedData);
 private void addContacts(String[] selectedItems) {

    manager.Insert_phone_contact(selectedItems);
    Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);    
    startActivity(i);
}
```

SQLite database method to insert contacts is as follows:

```
public void Insert_phone_contact(String [] contact){
    try{

        SQLiteDatabase DB = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        for(int i=0;i<contact.length;i++){
           // put all values in  ContentValues
            cv.put(CONTACT_NAME, contact[i]);
        }
        DB.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, cv); // insert in db
        DB.close();  // call close
        }
    catch(Exception ex){
        Log.e("Error in phone contact insertion", ex.toString());
    }

}
```

After that used SMS receiver to receive SMS for those specific contacts that have been saved in DB as follows :

```
// get instance of SMS manager
final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    try {

    final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();


        if (bundle != null) {

            //—retrieve the SMS message received—
            Object messages[] = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            SmsMessage smsMessage[] = new SmsMessage[messages.length];

            for (int n = 0; n < messages.length; n++) {
                smsMessage[n] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[n]);
                timestamp = smsMessage[n].getTimestampMillis();

                number = smsMessage[n].getOriginatingAddress();
                body += smsMessage[n].getDisplayMessageBody();
                }
            DBmanager = new DbManager(context);
            cursor = DBmanager.Return_All_Contacts();
            contactArr = showcontactsInfo(cursor);

            for(int i= 0;i<=contactArr.length;i++)
            {
                for (int j=0; j<=contactObj.selectedData.length ;j++){
                    if(contactArr[i].equals(contactObj.selectedData[j]))        
                    {
                        abortBroadcast();
                        blockMessage(context);
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(context, "No contact selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    }


                }
            }

        } // end for loop
    } // bundle is null

    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);

    }

}
private String[] showcontactsInfo(Cursor cursor) {
    String[] contact = new String [cursor.getCount()];

    int i= 0;
    while(cursor.moveToNext()){

        contact[i] = cursor.getString(1);

        i++;
    }
    return contact;
}
```

But can't filter SMS on the basis of contacts saved. Any useful help will be highly appreciated..

Comment: what is the error in logcat?

Comment: Exception smsReceiver java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Could you post the stack trace?